# How to add delimiters to each paragraphs using PDFBox (SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, backend, pdfbox

I'm reading a PDF file and converting it to text using PDFBox. But I need to put delimiters to each paragraphs. Let's suppose I am having a PDF file which looks like below:

```
This is a small demonstration .pdf file -

just for use in the Question. More text. And more
text. And more text. And more text. And more text.

And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more
text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And
more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text.
And more text. And more text.
```

**I need to get the output as below:
**

```
This is a small demonstration .pdf file -

-

just for use in the Question. More text. And more
text. And more text. And more text. And more text.

-

And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more
text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And
more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text.
And more text. And more text.

-
```

Tried checking the below code:

```
 if (text.endsWith("\n\n")) {
       
        // add the delimiter before the newline character
        text = text + DELIMITER;

        System.out.println("PdfProcessor text "+ text);
    }
```

but its only putting delimiter(in my case its a -) before the 1st paragraph. How can this be solved.

Comment: checking with "endsWith("\n\n")" will only return a boolean. Why would you assume it would add such a line? I'm not familiar with PDFProcessor per se, but it might be you can make a layout of your pdf, fill the text fields with your data, and between them, add the delimiters

Comment: Hey @Stultuske, I had done like this
      
` if (text.endsWith("\n\n")) {
            text = text + DELIMITER;

            System.out.println("PdfProcessor text "+ text);
        }
`

Comment: don't add code in comments, edit your question, and add all the relevant code in there. if it only 'marks' the first paragraph, chances are, you are only executing it for that text, or there is something different with the other texts but we can't really speculate with the little information you've given us

Comment: Hi! Updated now

Comment: have you tried putting and else block, and print something like: "[" + text +"]" ? it might be there are spaces after your breaks, if so, it doesn't end with what you test for.